# Oracle select distinct syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle, boolean

Why oracle doesn't recognize this sentence ? It says "From keyword" wasn't found where expected. What's wrong with it ?

Example:

```
select distinct a.id = b.id
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.column = X and b.column =Y;
```

MySQL allows me to do that. So what should I change ?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: i'm expecting some kind of boolean result, that's i why placed the '=' sign there and didn't use `a.id, b.id`.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought.  Boolean is not a standard SQL datatype.  MySQL has implemented it but Oracle has not.

Comment: Yep, that's what i said "some kind of boolean". i handle it with 1 and 0.

Comment: @APC: actually `boolean` *is* a standard SQL datatype (I think it was added with SQL-99). And MySQL does **not** have a `boolean` datatype - only a bit datatype which not entirely the same thing. MySQL simply treats zero as `false` and anything non-zero as `true` in an expression (which is something completely different than a real boolean type). That's why the (theoretically illegal) statement: `delete from foo where 1234` will happily delete all rows from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Oracle does not have a boolean data type in SQL (there is a boolean data type in PL/SQL) so a query cannot return a boolean.

You can do something like

```
select distinct (case when a.id = b.id 
                      then 1
                      else 0
                  end)
  from table1 a, 
       table2 b
 where a.column = X 
   and b.column = Y;
```

It strikes me as terribly unlikely, however, that you really want to do a Cartesian product between `table1` and `table2` only to then apply a `DISTINCT` operator.  Frequently, people incorrectly add a `DISTINCT` to a query when what they really want to do is add another join condition.  I would expect that you really want

```
select distinct (case when a.id = b.id 
                      then 1
                      else 0
                  end)
  from table1 a, 
       table2 b
 where a.some_key = b.some_key
   and a.column = X 
   and b.column = Y;
```

Once you have the join defined correctly, you may no longer need the expense of the extra `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that a.id = b.id is not valid sql when it's in the select clause.

**Edit Below**

Given your comment about expecting a boolean result, maybe you are looking for a case construct.

```
select case when a.id = b.id then 1 else 0 end BooleanResult
from tablea a join tableb b on something
where etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is it

```
select distinct a.id, b.id
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.column = X and b.column =Y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use decode in oracle

```
select distinct (decode (a.id,b.id,1,0)) from table1 a, table2 b
    where a.some_key = b.some_key
    and a.column = X ;
```